# Actualizar RecyclerView Adapter en un Fragment desde un Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil en Android. Tengo un TabLayout con dos tabs y cada uno es un fragment. En el primer fragment tengo un RecyclerView que me gustaría actualizar.

En el `MainActivity`, tengo un AlertDialog para ingresar datos y guardarlos localmente, luego, la idea es actualizar el RecyclerView Adapter para presentar los datos nuevos.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new StudentsFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_students));
        adapter.addFragment(new ReportsFragment(), getString(R.string.tab_reports));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_student:
                addStudent();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void addStudent() {
        final AlertDialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_student, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText nameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        Button addButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Aquí guardo el dato localmente

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String name = studentList.get(position).getName();
        holder.nameTextView.setText(name);
    }

    // Método para actualizar el Adapter
    public void updateRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;
        private TextView nameTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        }

    }

}
```

StudentsFragment

```
public class StudentsFragment extends Fragment {

    public StudentsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, container, false);

        final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(fragmentActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(fragmentActivity);
                fragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Solo tengo el método para actualizar el Adapter dentro del RecyclerViewAdapter. Pero, cómo lo puedo llamar desde MainActivity?

Mi objetivo es, cuando el usuario abre el AlertDialog desde MainActivity e ingrese un dato, luego de guardarlo, actualizar el RecyclerViewAdapter para presentar los datos nuevos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es guardar la referencia a los fragments, para llamar a algun metodo publico del fragment que se encargue de actualizar el adapter. Yo haria esto:

```
 //En el activity agrego los fragmentes del pager como propiedades del activity:     
 StudentsFragment mStudentsFragment = new StudentsFragment()
 ReportsFragment mReportsFragment = new ReportsFragment()

 //Aca remplazo las nuevas instancias por las que ya tengo guardadas
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(mStudentsFragment, getString(R.string.tab_students));
        adapter.addFragment(mReportsFragment, getString(R.string.tab_reports));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

private void addStudent() {
    final AlertDialog dialog;
    ...

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Despues de haber guardado los datos le indicamos al fragment que se actualize
            mStudentsFragment.updateStudents()
        }
    });
}
```

Ahora en el fragment vamos a agregar el metodo updateStudents() que simplemente actualiza el adapter

```
public class StudentsFragment extends Fragment {

  RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, container, false);

    final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(fragmentActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Importante! vamos a necesitar guardar la referencia al adapter
            mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(fragmentActivity);
            fragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);//Ahora usamos mAdapter que ya esta guardado
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return view;
  }


  //Una buena opcion para pasar los datos al adapter es justamente ponerlos como parametro de este metodo y luego pasarlos al adapter
  public void updateStudents(){
     //Aca deberias actualizar los datos del adapter... en el codigo no veo dodne le cargas los datos, pero aqui deberias actualizarlos y luego hacer el notifyDataSetChanged() que le indicara que tiene que refrescar el recycler y actualizar lo que esta mostrando.
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
}
```

Comment: En lugar de hacer `notifyDataSetChanged` en el Fragment, llamaré el método `updateRecyclerViewAdapter` que ya tengo en el `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Bueno, hay muchas formas, pero, me has dado la idea. Gracias amigo!.